# ssl_error_rx_record_too_long (FF/Django/StartSSL/Windows)

Tags: apache-2.2, windows, ssl, httpd

I've been trying to get SSL to work but I'm stuck. I tried several solutions offered here and on other Google results but no luck.

I got a free certificate from https://www.startssl.com/, Im using a Windows server, client is Firefox (code ssl_error_rx_record_too_long, other browsers give something less informative). I am trying to use Django but the request never makes it to the server so I think that's unrelated; nothing is displayed in the console. Apache shows no errors for httpd.

The http (not https) version of the site is working normally. Adding :443 to the https request does not change the error.

The (I think) relevant part of httpd config is:

```
Listen 80

LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so

DefaultType text/plain

<IfModule ssl_module>
    SSLRandomSeed startup builtin
    SSLRandomSeed connect builtin
</IfModule>

Listen 443

NameVirtualHost 85.223.64.8:80
Include "C:/Users/Mark/Web/Apache/httpd.conf.incl"

<VirtualHost _default_:443>
    # Include expanded
    LogLevel warn
    ErrorLog "path/secure.error.log"

    DocumentRoot "path/www"
    ServerName django.mverleg.nl
    ServerAdmin postmaster@mverleg.nl
    ServerAlias *.django.mverleg.nl
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyRequests Off

    SSLEngine on

    SSLSessionCache 'shmcb:path/ssl_scache(512000)'
    SSLSessionCacheTimeout 300

    SSLProtocol all -SSLv2
    SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT:!SSLv2:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM

    SSLCertificateFile "path/ssl.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "path/ssl.key"
    SSLCertificateChainFile "path/sub.class1.server.ca.pem"
    SSLCACertificateFile "path/ca.pem"

    <Location />
        UseCanonicalName Off
        ServerSignature Off
        AddDefaultCharset utf-8
        ProxyPass http://127.0.0.1:8081/
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Running test for httpd gives nothing. Error log when restarting:

```
The Apache2.2 service is restarting.
Starting the Apache2.2 service
The Apache2.2 service is running.
Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
httpd.exe: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 85.223.64.8 for ServerName
[Wed Jan 04 01:39:58 2012] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Wed Jan 04 01:39:58 2012] [notice] Digest: done
```

After which htppd.exe is *not* running (and hence no errors or response on page request).

If I comment the VirtualHost part, the next line after the above is:

```
[Wed Jan 04 01:41:52 2012] [notice] Apache/2.2.14 (Win32) DAV/2 mod_ssl/2.2.21 OpenSSL/0.9.8l configured -- resuming normal operations
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I thought everything is set up according to various guides I found so I can't see what's wrong (admitted I don't know much about SSL or httpd settings).

*Updated version already implementing some of the suggestions below and show error.*

**Unbelievable, it broke again... Http sites were working and https site was saying identity could not be verified (which is a step forward I guess). Then I restart the server and back to the old situation (nothing accessible). I reverted the changed (I think so...) and it's still broken. Any chance this is related to caching or storing keys or something like that, as it worked for a while when I added the new mod_ssl? None of this makes any sense, it's driving me crazy... Any ideas?** Got a new error:

```
[Wed Jan 04 03:30:45 2012] [crit] (OS 18)There are no more files.  : master_main: create child process failed. Exiting.
```

Comment: Check in the Apache error_log for some additional information about this request.

Comment: Is this *all* of the configuration?  On most instances in Linux, the main httpd.conf file includes a subdirectory with additional configuration.  There is usually one for SSL there. conf.d/ssl.conf.  Not sure about Windows builds...  Also, the suggestion to check error_log is misguided, as ssl_error_log is usually seperate.  Again, unsure about Apache under Windows.  Lastly, take care of the error about your FQDN by providing it in your hosts file.

Comment: Yeah there was an include but I hadn't enabled it. I fixed the domain name thing, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

SSL clearly isn't enabled at the minute on that IP address on port 443 (`http://85.223.64.8:443/` works as plain HTTP).

Please double check you have enabled `mod_ssl` (via `LoadModule` somewhere in your configuration, depending on what you're using).

If you haven't specified an `NameVirtualHost` directive, try using `<VirtualHost _default_:443>` instead of specifying your IP address.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I have NameVirtualHost now (with IP cause I think that's what I'll need if other sites are added later). Another problem appeared, I'll update the question.

Comment: You shouldn't need `NameVirtualHost` here. Multiple HTTPS sites together will cause other problems (especially if you try to run them on the same IP address).

Comment: I added the _default_ but regretably no improvement :-(

Answer (score 0):

Your `IfModule` line doesn't look right.  I believe it should be:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    SSLRandomSeed startup builtin
    SSLRandomSeed connect builtin
</IfModule>
```

Not:

```
<IfModule ssl_module>
    SSLRandomSeed startup builtin
    SSLRandomSeed connect builtin
</IfModule>
```

Comment: According to the [IfModule documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.1/mod/core.html#ifmodule), either the module name or the source file name can be used. It shouldn't matter.

Comment: Well look at that!  I still learn something new every day.  Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Not sure, but `ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8082/` could help (docs at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.1/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypassreverse ).

Comment: I looked it up, I think it is for rewriting headers in content you send to the client, right? I'm not really sure for what to use this, could you please explain?